# Python Flask CSRF token is giving unexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to implement csrf but I am confused as how this works.
My python file.

```py
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect, CSRFError
csrf = CSRFProtect()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'FlaskAppKey'
csrf.init_app(app)
```

My js file.

```js
       var csrftoken = "{{ csrf_token () }}";
       $.ajax(
       {
    url: '/calendar_data/',
    dataType:'json',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data:dataString,
    beforeSend:function(xhr,settings)
    {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        },
```

The `request.header` dump shows.

```js
X-Csrftoken: IjQ5NjYxOWRiYzgwOWU1N2Q0OWY0MmUxMDRjOGU1ZDcwNGUwNTJkM
```

If I remove the token the site doesn't error.

I have an error route.  So I am unsure if I am implementing everything correctly.  Once I removed the token from the code I was expecting an error.

```py
      @app.errorhandler(CSRFError)
      def handle_csrf_error(e):
  print(e)
  return ''
```

If the token isn't sent shouldn't the request error?

routes page

```
@app.route("/calendar_data/")
def calendar_data():
    stuff
return jsonify(data=data[1])
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your blueprint or route functions?

Comment: just added the routes data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to test with a `POST` request instead.

This might not answer your question directly, but rather guide you towards the WTF-Forms behavior. Have you tried sending a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request? The reason why I ask is because usually the protection will be against insertion of data, and specifically in `POST` requests (A lot more information on [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115794/should-i-use-csrf-protection-for-get-requests).

Also, according to the [docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) you can set up your `beforeSend` ajax method to the following:

```js
 var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
            }
        }
    });

## this should also technically exclude the CSRF token from the header
```

If you do try with `POST` requests, just make sure to accept it on your route:

```py
@app.route("/calendar_data/", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def calendar_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print ('posted')
    stuff
return jsonify(data=data[1])
```

From my understanding that case will not work if you do not pass the CSRF-token to the POST request, or if it is somehow malformed.

**Some more on CSRF in GET Requests**

According to [this cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) on CSRF security tokens:

> > The ideal solution is to only include the CSRF token in POST requests and modify server-side actions that have state changing affect to only respond to POST requests. This is in fact what the RFC 2616 requires for GET requests. If sensitive server-side actions are guaranteed to only ever respond to POST requests, then there is no need to include the token in GET requests.

Also, according to [rfc7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1):

> > Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are
> > essentially read-only

> > Of the request methods defined by this specification, the GET, HEAD,
> > OPTIONS, and TRACE methods are defined to be safe.